# Qt Quick Controls 2 Preferences window on macOs

Tags: macos, qt, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

Is there any way to add standard `About` and `Preferences...` menu items using Qt Quick Controls 2?

[image: Mac OS menu bar]

Qt version 5.7, macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Menu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html) and [`MenuItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menuitem.html) from [`Controls 2`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls2-qmlmodule.html).

```
Button {
    id: fileButton
    text: "File"
    onClicked: menu.open()

    Menu {
        id: menu
        y: fileButton.height

        MenuItem {
            text: "New..."
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Open..."
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Save"
        }
    }
}
```

Controls 2 doesn't appear to have a `MenuBar` element thou. But it is essentially just a row of buttons which open menus plus a filler for the bar, anchored to the top of the window. So you can easily do it yourself.

The downside of using controls 2 is that it doesn't seem to support native menu styles.

Good news - the upcoming 5.8 release will come with the [`Qt.labs.platform`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qtlabsplatform-index.html) module, which provides platform native controls, there is a menu bar, menu, menu item, menu groups and separators.

Comment: Yes, I know how to make window/view/dialog. But how to add menu item into menubar?

Comment: Set MenuItem.PreferencesRole for a MenuItem from Qt Labs Platform: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qt-labs-platform-menuitem.html#role-prop